# Android REST API search file

Tags: android, rest, sdk, drive

With this code I'm trying to get metadata from a file that is in google drive.
When I test the application in the debug version, I can find the file and the related matadata.
But when i test the application in release mode, I can find the file but no metadata. I state that I have enabled Drive API, created the project and credentials in the console. Thanks for your help

```
 public static ArrayList<ContentValues> searchDB(String titl) {
    ArrayList<ContentValues> gfs = new ArrayList<>();
    if (mGOOSvc != null && mConnected)
        try {                 
            Drive.Files.List qry = mGOOSvc.files().list()
                    .setQ("title = '" + titl + "'");
            Log.d("qry", qry + "");
            String npTok = null;
            if (qry != null) do {
                FileList gLst = qry.execute();
                Log.d("gLst", gLst + "");
                if (gLst != null) {
                    for (File gFl : gLst.getItems()) {
                        Log.d("gFl", gLst.getItems() + "");
                        if (gFl.getLabels().getTrashed()) continue;
                        gfs.add(UT_drive_dropbox.newCVs(gFl.getTitle(), gFl.getId(), gFl.getMimeType(), gFl.getModifiedByMeDate().toString(), gFl.getLastModifyingUser().getDisplayName()));
                        UT_drive_dropbox.AM.setNomeEcognome(gFl.getLastModifyingUser().getDisplayName());
                        UT_drive_dropbox.AM.setFoto(gFl.getLastModifyingUser().getPicture().getUrl());

                    }                                                                 //else UT.lg("failed " + gFl.getTitle());
                    npTok = gLst.getNextPageToken();
                    qry.setPageToken(npTok);
                }
            }
            while (npTok != null && npTok.length() > 0);
            //UT.lg("found " + vlss.size());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            UT_drive_dropbox.le(e);
        }
    return gfs;
}
```

In the release mode I can find the file

```
Log.d("qry", qry + "");//file name
```

but the list is empty

```
Log.d("gLst", gLst + "");
```

Comment: Have you set the API key for release mode? What is the header response from the HTTP request?

Comment: I did everything necessary. For the release version, the problem seems to be this row `FileList gLst = qry.execute();`

Comment: If it is working fine in debug, but not in release, the only thing I can think of is that you are using your debug key on a release build. If you can somehow get the entire HTTP response from your rest call, and not just that FileList, the server might actually be returning the error that the call is encountering.